# Java: changeable timer for a small game

Tags: java, timer

In the series of my Boggle questions here's the next.

I need a timer that is customizable by the player. Before a game of Boggle starts, the player can choose a time between 30 and 180 seconds. I tried it with a `Timer` linked to a `TimerTask`, this works in the first run of the game but when I go change the seconds in the `TimerTask` and do another run it says task is busy or has been cancelled. What's the best way to implement a timer that gets reset when a game starts and has a customizable time limit. Can a `Timer`/ `TimerTask` be reset?

**The code:**

class CountDown:

```
public class CountDown {
Timer timer;
DisplayCountDown displayCountDown;

public CountDown(DisplayCountDown displayCountDown) {
    timer = new Timer();
    this.displayCountDown = displayCountDown;
    timer.schedule(this.displayCountDown, 0, 1000);
}

public DisplayCountDown getDisplayCountDown() {
    return displayCountDown;
}

public Timer getTimer() {
    return timer;
}
}
```

class DisplayCountDown:

```
public class DisplayCountDown extends TimerTask {
private int seconds = 30;

public void run() {
    if(seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
    this.seconds = seconds;
}

public int getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
}
}
```

To reset the timer I try this:

```
countDown = null;
countDown = new CountDown(displayCountDown);
```

I get this error when I run it a second time:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or     cancelled`

EDIT: what's wrong? Why does this get so much negative reputation? I'm not asking for you guys to just give me a solution, I know you guys hate it and that's not at all what I want... I just want to get back on track, a name of a class would be enough for me... For all clearness: I'm not asking for a finished solution, just for some tips :/

Comment: You said you tried to reset the timer but get an error. If you include the code that shows how you create / restart the timer, you might get some better responses. I think this is a fine question just needs some polish: +1 to counteract some of the downvotes

Comment: In your series of boggle questions ? So to answer this I need to look back through your questions?  Please provide required information and any relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Mark No no not at all ;) This is just another question because I have been asking a lot of Boggle-related questions lately, but this should be pretty straight-forward, I've provided some code ;)

Answer (score 2):

"If the timer's task execution thread terminates unexpectedly, for example, because its stop method is invoked, any further attempt to schedule a task on the timer will result in an IllegalStateException, as if the timer's cancel method had been invoked."

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

So, one solution would be to create a new Timer after you've cancelled the first.

Another solution would be: Instead of stopping and starting the timer, you could keep one timer going forever, and have all DisplayCountDown instances subscribe to the global timer (e.g. by filling out a list, and having the timer iterate over the list and notifying every DisplayCountDown)